# How to use a variable as an external module in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm converting our old js-files (commonjs) to ts-files, and one of them use an external library that have it's own .d.ts-files.

The library is already loaded in to the global variable FullCalendar.

So I want to do something like:

```
declare var FullCalendar: @fullcalendar/core;
```

but thats not correct syntax.

If I reference it like this:

```
/// <reference path="../fullcalendar/packages/core/main.d.ts" />
import * as FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/core";
```

my IDE thinks everything is fine, but in the js file I get this row:

```
const FullCalendar = require("@fullcalendar/core");
```

If I insted use:

```
declare var FullCalendar: any;
```

the code compiles and work as intended, but my IDE no longer know what type it is.

Is there a way to declare the variable with the right type, where the compiled js dosn't try to overwrite the variable?

Answer (score 0):

The ket seams to be to use the `typeof import`

```
/// <reference path="../fullcalendar/packages/core/main.d.ts" />
declare const FullCalendar: typeof import('@fullcalendar/core');
```